# Background pattern jumping when animating UIScrollView.contentOffset manually

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, core-animation

I'm attempting to animate the `contentOffset` of a `UIScrollView` by hand using the old-style `[UIView beginAnimations:context:]` method. I'm animating it instead of using `setContentOffset:animated:` because I want to control the duration. I'm using the old-style method rather than using blocks because I'm targeting iOS 3 and above (as an aside, is that a valid thing to do?).

When it animates, the subviews animate fine, but the background pattern jumps as if it wasn't being animated at all.

Does anyone know if there's anything special I have to do to get this work?

Thanks!

**Edit**: Current bodge is to have a vanilla UIView with its own background pattern within the scroll view. Far from ideal though :-(

Comment: As far as being valid, Apple generally recommends you check whether features exist and use them if (and only if, obviously) they're there.  And blocks have been in Obj-C since before 3.0, haven't they?

Comment: Hmm, well all the old-style animation docs say "Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later." But perhaps I don't understand the difference between Deployment Target and Base SDK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is autoScrolling / programmatically scrolling. Here it is
http://www.aaron.griffith.name/weblog/2011/02/23/scrolling-a-uiscrollview-programmatically/

Comment: Yeah, I'm scrolling programatically in another of my scroll views. I was just hoping to avoid that. It seems kind of wrong to have to do all the animation by hand with timers given that all the properties that I'm animating theoretically *should* be animatable using "proper" methods, right? Hmm.